# C# Creating a calculator using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning mvc and trying to create a simple calculator. I have most of the work done, but i cant seem to work the calculation part using javaScript.
The result that is displayed in the browser is almost complete and is like that: 5 + 2 = 0.

This is the view where the result of  the calculation will be displayed in the browser, also where i thought the calculation part should be (currect me if i'm wrong):

```
@model CalculatorWebPage.Models.Calc

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>CalculateResult</title>
       <script>
        if (@Model.Operator == '+')
        {
            @Model.Result = @Model.FirstNumber + @Model.SecondNumber;
        }
        else if (@Model.Operator == '-')
        {
            @Model.Result = @Model.FirstNumber - @Model.SecondNumber;
        }
        else if (@Model.Operator == '*')
        {
            @Model.Result = @Model.FirstNumber * @Model.SecondNumber;
        }
        else if (@Model.Operator == '/')
        {
            @Model.Result = @Model.FirstNumber / @Model.SecondNumber;
        }
        return @Model.Result;

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Model.FirstNumber @Model.Operator @Model.SecondNumber = @Model.Result
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this is the place and the way to put the javeScript code to calculate?

Comment: Can you share you controller code? And what do you mean by not working? Does it give you any error? Is it giving unexpected output, what output is shown ? What is expected output?

Comment: Why do you calculate in your view? This isn't how MVC is meant to be.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih I'm new to MVC and learning how to work it. so sorry if i try to calculate in my view. i guess i didnt get to the part where i should calculate and came here for a little help/..

Comment: You need to actually write the JS function and then call it. See https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events_onclick

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Its not calculating anything. Like i wrote in the question, the display in the browser after i hit the 'Calculate' button is: 5 * 2 = 0. Meaning it show me the currect data but not the currect Calculation result.

Comment: @Dolev Model: stores data, View: shows model info, Controller: calculates, does action, modifies model. I'll write a calculator MVC example for you.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Thank you Janes. This is why i came to this site for guidance, i know there are skilled people who could help me insted of attacking and downvoting every thing that moves.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih  it's ok i know i could figure it out by my self, i just wanted to know if i'm on the right track or not.
you dont have to write calculator example for me.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih little question: if i do the calculation in the controller it means i need to pass the parameters in the Post Action and the calculation methos write just above the "return view" ?

Comment: @Dolev: Yes, `return View(modelObj)` passes the model object to the view.
I'll upload my example in a few second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, I wouldn't calculate anything in the `View` since its only objective is to show or view your data which you stored in your `Model`.
A simple MVC calculator should look like this.
You have your `CalculationModel`, which stores the info:

```
public class CalculationModel
{
    public decimal FirstNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal SecondNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Result { get; set; }
    public CalculationMethod calculationMethod { get; set; } 
}
```

I used an `Enum` here to represent all possible calculation methods:

```
public enum CalculationMethod
{
    Addition = '+',
    Subtraction = '-',
    Multiplication = '*', 
    Division = '/'
}
```

Your View then should only use the info provided by your model and show it in `Labels`, `Textboxes`, etc.

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.CalculationModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Calculation", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstNumber)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecondNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SecondNumber)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Result) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Result)<br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.calculationMethod, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CalculationMethod))))
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Then finally you have your `Controller` which handles all the action.

Depending on your config, you have a method that handles your request (`HttpPost or HttpGet`) and one that simply shows your empty `View`:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(CalculationModel model)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    switch (model.calculationMethod)
    {
        case CalculationMethod.Addition:
            model.Result = model.FirstNumber + model.SecondNumber;
            break;
        case CalculationMethod.Subtraction:
            model.Result = model.FirstNumber - model.SecondNumber;
            break;
        case CalculationMethod.Multiplication:
            model.Result = model.FirstNumber * model.SecondNumber;
            break;
        case CalculationMethod.Division:
            model.Result = model.FirstNumber / model.SecondNumber;
            break;
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Et voìla, MVC pattern fulfilled ;)

`ModelState.Clear();` in the `Controller` "refreshes" all the `Textboxes` your data is stored in, otherwise the `Result` wouldn't show.

**Small edit:**

If you don't the `DropDownList` to show the `Value` (e.g. `Addition`) but want to show a `DisplayName`, you can do the following with MVC5 (tested in ASP.NET Core 2.0 preview1):

Replace `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.calculationMethod, ...)` with

```
<select asp-for="calculationMethod" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof (CalculationMethod))"></select>
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.calculationMethod, (Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(CalculationMethod))))
```

Where the enum is now defined with the following properties:

```
public enum CalculationMethod
{
    [Display(Name = "+")]
    Addition,
    [Display(Name = "-")]
    Subtraction,
    [Display(Name = "*")]
    Multiplication,
    [Display(Name = "/")]
    Division
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Model value is not updating.
Try this

```
 if (@Model.Operator == '+')
   {
      document.getElementById('Result').value = @Model.FirstNumber + @Model.SecondNumber;
   }
```